# Error while adding click listeners to the menu items of a navigation drawer using View Binding

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewbinding

When I try to add click listeners to the menu items using `binding.navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener`, it throws me an error saying **Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type NavigationView?**

So when I add the safe call like this: `binding.navigationView?.setNavigationItemSelectedListener`, naturally the click listener doesn't work, neither do i get my toast message on clicking on the menu items nor does the fragment I've added in the dashboard menu item work.

When I add the non null asserted call, the app altogether crashes and gives me **nullPointerException** in the logcat.

Here is the kotlin code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setUpToolbar()

        val actionBarDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(          
            this@MainActivity,
            binding.root,
            R.string.open_drawer,
            R.string.close_drawer)
        binding.root.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle)       
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()

        binding.navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {

            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.dashboard -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frameLayout, DashboardFragment())
                    .commit()

                binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawers()
                }
                R.id.favourites -> {
                    Toast.makeText (
                        this@MainActivity,
                        "Clicked on favourites",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
                R.id.profile -> {
                    Toast.makeText (
                        this@MainActivity,
                        "Clicked on profile",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
                R.id.aboutApp -> {
                    Toast.makeText (
                        this@MainActivity,
                        "Clicked on about",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            }

            return@setNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }


    }

    fun setUpToolbar(){
        supportActionBar?.title = "Toolbar Title"               
        supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)            
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)      
    }
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {     
        val id = item.itemId                                            
        if(id == android.R.id.home){                                    
            binding.root.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)               
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

here is the xml code:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity = "start"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

It'd be great if someone could point out where I'm going wrong

Comment: Check if `navigationView` is defined in all versions of `activity_main.xml` in your project. It seems that `navigationView` is null when bindings are generated. This happens when all `activity_main.xml` do not have same view defined in them.

Comment: You're most welcome. Please upvote my comment.